# Does Firebase have built-in functionality to retrieve random items?

Tags: javascript, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm planning on doing a Firebase project with thousands (probably tens of thousands) of items in the realtime database, and need to be able to both order, filter and pick a random item. I can of course do the randomization on the client, but if Firebase already has this functionality, it would be better.

I have done some searching, and most of the related hits are 2-3 years old and states that this is not available. Does anyone know if the support is here now in late 2016?

Comment: please explain your problem with an example

Comment: Nothing significant changed in that respect: there is no built-in operator to retrieve a random item from a list of items. You will have to roll your own.